# Does solr replication not work while data import is in progress on master?

Tags: solr, solr5

I have setup solr master slave architecture to separate read and write traffic to our solr machines. The 'replicateAfter' parameter is set as 'commit,startup' on master configuration.The configuration works fine except for a one glitch.Whenever data import is running on master,the data gets deleted on slave machine.Do we need to disable replication before running data import on master?

I have read solr official documentation but it doesn't provide any insights regarding the same.

Comment: If you are deleting the data from the master before you reimport, yes, you'll need to disable replication otherwise the deletions will replicate to the other copy.

Comment: I am doing full import.By default 'clean' parameter is true.I suspect that is the cause.